# How to get Jest to parse glsl files?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, glsl

I am working on a React project that includes the vtk.js library. I am getting the following error while running test cases with Jest:

APP_PATH_HERE\node_modules\vtk.js\Sources\Rendering\OpenGL\glsl\vtkPolyDataVS.glsl:18

```
attribute vec4 vertexMC;
          ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1350:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/vtk.js/Sources/Rendering/OpenGL/PolyDataMapper/index.js:11:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it fixed the problem adding module mapper to jest configuration:

```json
jest: {
 "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^.+.(vert|frag|glsl)$": "jest-transform-stub"
    }
}
```

it requires installing dev dependency "jest-transform-stub"